# Matlab gui overwrite folder

Tags: matlab

The gui has to save various output files and I want the user to select a folder where to save them.

Main problem is that when I use `uigetdir` the user can only select folders that already exist and when I use `uiputfile` the user can only select a folder that does not exist (typing the name they want the folder to have).

I want to be able to select both existing and non existing folders, how can that be done in matlab?

Comment: AFAIK `uigetdir` has a button that allows you to create new folders... give it a try!

Comment: Yes, but it is not exaclty what I am looking for, I want to be able to just navigate to a place, write or select a folder and if it already esixts, overwrite it.